# How to add spaces in print() after combining multiple dataframes in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('DelayedFlights.csv')

df["final"] = 
df["Year"].map(str)+df["FlightNum"].map(str)+df["Origin"]+df["Dest"]

print(df["final"].head()) #map converts the non string data types to string
```

The output shows :

```
0     2008335IADTPA
1    20083231IADTPA
2     2008448INDBWI
3    20083920INDBWI
4     2008378INDJAX
Name: final, dtype: object
```

The output I want :

```
0    2008 335 IAD TPA
1    2008 3231 IAD TPA
2    2008 448 IND BWI
3    2008 3920 IND BWI
4    2008 378 IND JAX
Name: final, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
df["final"] = df["Year"].map(str)+ ' ' + df["FlightNum"].map(str)+ ' ' + df["Origin"]+ ' ' + df["Dest"]
```

Comment: Maybe the wrong place to ask this question, but is there a way to insert multiple spaces when I join the columns? I tried `df['A'] + '             ' + df['B']`, but it still gives me just one space. What shall I do? Thanks. (Edit, it seems like SO doesn't allow me to do it either, I put in 5 or 6 spaces,

Answer (score 0):

```
add_space = lambda x: str(x) + " "
df["final"] = df["Year"].map(add_space) + df["FlightNum"].map(add_space) + df["Origin"].map(add_space) + df["Dest"]
```

Not a pandas expert, but it seems from the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and your example that the map method can take a function, so if you want an extra space when formatting, just create a lambda that converts it to a string then adds an extra space when called.

Or alternatively, using `format`

```
df["final"] = df["Year"].map("{} ".format) + df["FlightNum"].map("{} ".format) + df["Origin"].map("{} ".format) + df["Dest"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A single-line option:

```
df['final'] =  df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(x['Year']), str(x['FlightNum']), x['Origin'], x['Dest']]), axis=1)
```

And for a dynamic function that combines the text in all columns:

```
df['final'] = df.apply(lambda row: ' '.join([str(col) for col in row]), axis=1)
```

Or limited by user-defined list:

```
cols = ['Year','FlightNum','Origin','Dest']
df['final'] = df.apply(lambda row: ' '.join([str(col) for col in row if col in cols), axis=1)
```

Using `format`:

```
df['final'] = df.apply(lambda row: '{} {} {} {}'.format(row['Year'], row['FlightNum'], row['Origin'], row['Dest']), axis=1)
```